# SaveChangesException was unhandled "An error occured while processing this request."

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using early bound classes and upon calling SaveChanges() I'm getting this generic error message which tells me nothing.

The inner exception is "an unexpected error occured"

Tracing is turned on for the server and just reposts the same error message.

Is there some way to get useful information out of this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post up the code that is causing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning customErrors on in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in:

```
        try
        {
            //crm code here
        }
        // Catch any service fault exceptions that Microsoft Dynamics CRM throws.
        catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>)
        {
            // You can handle an exception here or pass it back to the calling method.
            throw;
        }
```

If you catch the specific exception that's being thrown it may shed more light on the problem. Failing that, post the code / ask it in a new question and we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

There is a details section in the soap exception, this usually includes some additional details that help resolve your problem.

```
try
{
    response = crm.Execute(request);
}
catch (SoapException e)
{
    //Console.Write(e.Detail.InnerXml);
    throw new Exception (e.Detail.InnerXml, e);
}
```